# Modifying a child Entity on delete of parent Entity

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I've got a `Person` class that can be an invitee to multiple `Events`. An Event keeps track of people and also a list of phonenumbers, for people that don't have a record in `Person`. When a `Person` gets deleted, we want to move their phone number to the list of phonenumbers for events that that person was invited to.

I've considered using `@PreRemove` in `Person`, but Spring doesn't like injecting an event repository in the User entity. Nor is there a way to save the particular Person within `@PreRmove` and do a cascade persist.

I've also considered doing an event listener, but I get a circular dependency error when I inject either an event or person repository inside there to perform a save on the events.

Is there a way to do to this in Spring?

Comment: have you tried [`@DomainEvents`](https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-domain-event/)? Thorben Janssen describes saving, but removing should work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Andrey for the suggestion. Following [this article](https://dev.to/kirekov/spring-data-power-of-domain-events-2okm) on `@DomainEvents`, I was able to get this working.